# Projective general linear group on discrete valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, valuation-theory

Let $R$ be a complete discrete valuation ring and $k$ its residue field.

Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of $PGL_2(k)$ such that its order is prime with char($k$).

Is there some elementary way to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $PGL_2(R)$?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Either we have $k \subset R$ (in the equal characteristic case, e.g. $R \simeq k((T))$), and then the statement is nearly trivial; or otherwise, in the unequal characteristic case, e.g. $R=\mathbb Z_p$, $k=\mathbb F_p$, the statement cannot be true because $PGL_2(k)$ is not naturally contained in $PGL_2(R)$.